# Reverse engineer optimized c code from assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, compiler-optimization

The point of this problem is to reverse engineer c code that was made after running the compiler with level 2 optimization.  The original c code is as follows (computes the greatest common divisor):

```
int gcd(int a, int b){
    int returnValue = 0;
    if (a != 0 &&  b != 0){
        int r;
        int flag = 0;
        while (flag == 0){
            r = a % b;
            if (r ==0){
                flag = 1;
            } else {
                a = b;
                b = r;
            }
        }
        returnValue = b;
    }
    return(returnValue);
}
```

when I ran the optimized compile I ran this from the command line:

```
gcc -O2 -S Problem04b.c
```

to get the assembly file for this optimized code

```
.gcd:
    .LFB12:
        .cfi_startproc
        testl   %esi, %esi
        je  .L2
        testl   %edi, %edi
        je  .L2
    .L7:
        movl    %edi, %edx
        movl    %edi, %eax
        movl    %esi, %edi
        sarl    $31, %edx
        idivl   %esi
        testl   %edx, %edx
        jne .L9
        movl    %esi, %eax
        ret
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
    .L2:
        xorl    %esi, %esi
        movl    %esi, %eax
        ret
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
    .L9:
        movl    %edx, %esi
        jmp .L7
        .cfi_endproc
```

I need to convert this assembly code back to c code here is where I am at right now:

```
int gcd(int a int b){
    /*
       testl %esi %esi
       sets zero flag if a is 0 (ZF) but doesn't store anything
       */
    if (a == 0){
        /*
           xorl %esi %esi
           sets the value of a variable to 0. More compact than movl
           */
        int returnValue = 0;
        /*
           movl %esi %eax
           ret

           return the value just assigned
           */
        return(returnValue);
    }
    /*
       testl %edi %edi
       sets zero flag if b is 0 (ZF) but doesn't store anything
       */
    if (b == 0){
        /*
           xorl %esi %esi
           sets the value of a variable to 0. More compact than movl
           */
        int returnValue = 0;
        /*
           movl %esi %eax
           ret

           return the value just assigned
           */
        return(returnValue);
    }

    do{
        int r = b;
        int returnValue = b;

    }while();


}
```

Can anyone help me write this back in to c code? I'm pretty much lost.

Comment: You should be lost, there is a rason, why there are no useful reverse-engineering-automatition-tools until now. Nevertheless, I am still curious about this and any answers.

Comment: You might benefit (perhaps only a little) by viewing generated assembly, that is intermixed with C code. Within `gdb` you could use `disas /m gcd`, or another way is `objdump` with `-S` flag.

Comment: You should compile with `gcc -fverbose-asm -O2 -S Problem04b.c` and you might use `-fdump-tree-all` to get a lot of intermediate dump files representing the internal representations at various stages of the compilation.

Comment: HexRays decompiler can be very useful in this situation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you have the values mixed in your code. `%esi` begins with the value `b` and `%edi` begins with the value `a`.

You can infer from the `testl   %edx, %edx` line that `%edx` is used as the condition variable for the loop beginning with `.L7` (if `%edx` is different from 0 then control is transferred to the `.L9` block and then returned to `.L7`). We'll refer to `%edx` as `remainder` in our reverse-engineered code.

---

Let's begin reverse-engineering the main loop:

```
movl    %edi, %edx
```

Since `%edi` stores `a`, this is equivalent to initializing the value of `remainder` with `a`: `int remainder = a;`.

```
movl    %edi, %eax
```

Store `int temp = a;`

```
movl    %esi, %edi
```

Perform `int a = b;` (remember that `%edi` is `a` and `%esi` is `b`).

`sarl    $31, %edx`

This arithmetic shift instruction shifts our `remainder` variable 31 bits to the right whilst maintaining the *sign* of the number. By shifting 31 bits you're setting `remainder` to 0 if it's positive (or zero) and to -1 if it's negative. So it's equivalent to `remainder = (remainder < 0) ? -1 : 0`.

`idivl   %esi`

Divide `%edx:%eax` by `%esi`, or in our case, divide `remainder * temp` by `b` (the variable). The *remainder* will be stored in `%edx`, or in our code, `remainder`. When combining this with the previous instruction: if `remainder < 0` then `remainder = -1 * temp % b`, and otherwise `remainder = temp % b`.

```
testl   %edx, %edx
jne .L9
```

Check to see if `remainder` is equal to 0 - if it's not, jump to `.L9`. The code there simply sets `b = remainder;` before returning to `.L7`. In order to implement this in C, we'll keep a `count` variable that will store the amount of times the loop has iterated. We'll perform `b = remainder` at the beginning of the loop but only after the first iteration, meaning when `count != 0`.

We're now ready to build our full C loop:

```
int count = 0;
do {
    if (count != 0)
        b = remainder;
    remainder = a;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    if (remainder < 0){
        remainder = -1 * temp % b;
    } else {
        remainder = temp % b;
    }

    count++;
} while (remainder != 0)
```

And after the loop terminates,

```
movl    %esi, %eax
ret
```

Will return the GCD that the program computed (in our code it'll be stored in the `b` variable).

Comment: I inserted your code into a c file and I don't think this is operating correctly.  I'm getting a floating point exception

Comment: @scottybobby Sorry, the variable names got all mixed up when I wrote the answer. It's fixed now.